# Adding headers to my php code?

Tags: php, email

I have been advised to add headers to my php code as my emails are coming through to my inbox with blank/empty form fields even though the user has iputted them on the webpage before clicking submit. I will be greatly appreciative if somebody can tell me if i have done this right?

```
<?php


$EmailFrom = "Quote@mydomian.co.uk";
$EmailTo = "me@mydomian.co.uk";
$Subject = "Online contact form";
$fullName = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['fullName'])); 
$contactNo = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactNo'])); 
$message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "fullName: ";
$Body .= $fullName;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "contactNo: ";
$Body .= $contactNo;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "message: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $headers, $EmailFrom");


// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=Thankyou.html\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.html\">";
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you also show your HTML. And is `Trim` your own function?

Comment: You have an extra **double-quote** in the variable **$success**

Comment: @putvande `trim` is a php library function.

Comment: Please post actual code. Clearly the posted code would result in a parse error.

Comment: @webbiedave. I know just thought it was case sensitive.

Comment: <form method="post" action="http://cm4u.co.uk/FinanceForms/FORMTESTING/newform.php">
            <label for="fullName">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="fullName" id="fullName" />

            <label for="contactNo">Tel</label>
            <input type="text" name="contactNo" id="contactNo" />

            <label for="message">Message</label>
            <textarea name="message" rows="10" id="message"></textarea>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="submit" id="submit"/>
            </form>

Comment: @putvande hi, I have just provided my html.. trim isnt my own function, As I am pretty new to php I have used the provided sample php script from 123-reg to help with contact forms thanks for replying x

Answer (score 0):

You should use the php header() function:

header('Content-type: application/html');

as this will be send first to the browser...

Comment: This is a processing page that sends an email. I don't think the main issue has anything to do with the HTML resulting on this page.

Answer (score 0):

here is example how to set from/sender/reply-to headers in e-mail message:

```
$headers = array(
        'From: sender name <senderemail@example.com>',
        'Sender: senderemail@example.com',
        'To: '.$to,
        'Reply-To: senderemail@example.com',
        'MIME-Version: 1.0',
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8',
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit',
);

if ($cc)
    $headers[] = 'CC: ' . $cc;
if ($bcc)
    $headers[] = 'BCC: ' . $bcc;

$response = @mail($to, $subject, $content, implode("\n", $headers), '-f senderemail@example.com');
```

NOTE: as you see there are many duplicate of sender's email address, but I've noticed that mail clients and mail senders (like sendmail) behave differently, so this is needed to handle possible configurations